# How can I sort a RadGridView by its GridViewSelectColumn?

Tags: wpf, sorting, telerik, radgridview

I would like the GridViewSelectColumn to alternate between ascending and descending sorting when its header is clicked, just as the other columns do. Is this possible?

I tried the following with no luck:

```
<telerik:GridViewSelectColumn UniqueName="Selected" IsSortable="True" />
```

I have also tried adding the following code to the constructor of my code-behind:

```
            ColumnSortDescriptor csd = new ColumnSortDescriptor
            {
                Column = this.myGrid.Columns["Selected"],
                SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending
            };
```

This didn't work, either.

I also tried hooking into the grid view's Sorting event, but it apparently doesn't get fired for this column type.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to use a collection view source for that, like it's described in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control)?

Comment: I have not, but am pretty sure that would do the trick. I was trying to get around doing that and just keep using the column that Telerik provides out of the box.